# Paypal integration with external paypal class

Tags: payment-gateways

I have a `paypal.class.php` at `SITE_URL/paypal/papal.class.php`   getting this error :

> Warning: include_once(/var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/includes/bootstrap.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/solution/public_html/taconsultant/paypal/paypal.class.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/includes/bootstrap.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home4/solution/public_html/taconsultant/paypal/paypal.class.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap() in /home4/solution/public_html/taconsultant/paypal/paypal.class.php on line 4

I am not able to access the `user_load()` function or any other Drupal function or variable in it. Is there a way to access Drupal variables in that particular file?

I have included it like this.

```
    require_once '../includes/bootstrap.inc';

    global $user;
    $uid =$user->uid;

        class paypal_class {

           var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

           var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

           var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
           var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
           var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

           var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal


           function paypal_class() {

              // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

              $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

              $this->last_error = '';

              $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
              $this->ipn_log = true; 
              $this->ipn_response = '';

              // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
              // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
              // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

              $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
              $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 

           }

           function add_field($field, $value) {

              // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
              // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
              // array, it will be overwritten.

              $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
           }
```

Comment: Just curious. Why do you want to do it with an external file? And why can't the class be a part of a module which could be enabled? There is a [Paypal](http://drupal.org/project/paypal) module already present, did you check if that could serve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks  AjitS to share this. actually i m kinda new to Drupal so i don't know about it.